# VNC greyed screen for Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, vnc

I have a remote ubuntu server 10.04 32 bit which I'd like to access with vnc. I followed this tut http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-VNC.html to install vncserver and then gnome core.

I connected successfully with tightvnc client but screen is just greyed why ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't have a windowmanager installed/configured. What are the contents of `.vnc/xstartup`, and what does `.vnc/$(hostname):1.log` say?